# Why does my data route only work partially?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

app.js initializes the allArticles as a global variable with the articles from the JSON file.

```
app.locals.allArticles = dataFile.articles;
```

articles.js (route) takes the app data and make it available in the articles.ejs page

```
router.get('/articles', function(req, res) {
  var data = req.app.get('appData');
  var articleTitles = data.articles;

  res.render('articles', {
    pageTitle: 'Articles',
    pageID: 'articles',
    articles: articleTitles
  });
});
```

header.ejs references allArticles as follows

```
<% allArticles.forEach(function(item) { %>
  <%= item.name %>
<% }); %>
```

**Issue**: reference to PageID or articles throws a reference error i.e.

```
allArticles is not defined
```

The weird thing is that the reference to pageTitle goes through..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully passed data from the JSON file into the views as follows:

app.js made articles array available to local routes:

```
app.locals.allArticles = dataFile.articles;
```

index.js (route) took in app data, created array to hold data, passed through data using forEach function, rendered in view:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var data = req.app.get('appData');
  var allArticles = [];

  data.articles.forEach(function(item) {
    allArticles = item.title;
  });

  res.render('index', {
    pageTitle: 'Home',
    pageID: 'home',
    articles: allArticles
  });
});
```

index.ejs (view):

```
<% allArticles.forEach(function(item) { %>
  <%= item.name %><br/>
<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a view variable named `articles` to your view, not `allArticles`. Rename one or the other so that they match and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `articles` as an object not an array, the array of articles I think it's `articleTitles`, so you could change the EJS code to:

```
<% articles.articles.forEach(function(item) { %>
  <%= item.name %>
<% }); %>
```